# Why is the controller not redirecting to specified route when posting form data via AJAX?

Tags: ajax, post, model-view-controller, slim

I am using Slim 3 framework, twig for managing templates and Eloquent ORM. My AuthController.php looks like this

```
class AuthController extends Controller{

    public function getSignUp($request, $response){
        return $this->view->render($response, 'auth/signup.twig');
    }

    public function postSignUp($request, $response){
        $user = User::create([

             'firstname' => $request->getParam('first-name'),
             'lastname' => $request->getParam('last-name'),
             'email' => $request->getParam('email'),
             'zipcode' => $request->getParam('zipcode'),
             'phonenumber' => $request->getParam('phone-number'),
             'username' => $request->getParam('username'),
             'password' => password_hash($request->getParam('password'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT)
        ]);

        return $response->withRedirect($this->router->pathFor('home'));
    }
}
```

The AJAX function written is as follows

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
            $('#signup').click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "{{ path_for('auth.signup') }}",
                    data: $(this).serialize()
                });
            });
        });
```

And routes.php has the following two routes concerned with the sign up process

```
$app->get('/auth/signup', 'AuthController:getSignUp')->setName('auth.signup');
$app->post('/auth/signup', 'AuthController:postSignUp');
```

Now everything is working fine. The data is correctly posted via AJAX and getting inserted in the 'users' table. But this code

```
return $response->withRedirect($this->router->pathFor('home'));
```

doesn't work. Even after the posting, no redirecting takes place. If the table is getting updated, that means that the inserting code in the postSignUp() function is working. Then why isn't the return statement working?

I am fairly new to Slim 3 framework as well as the MVC paradigm so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Why are you using an AJAX request when you want to redirect the user afterwards? Can't you use a "normal" form request?

Comment: Make sure that $this->router is properly initialized.